# Include columns not used for calculation in data.table result

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data table:

```
   id user V1 V2 V3 V4
1:  1    1  1  1  1  0
2:  1    2  4  1  3  1
3:  1    3  0  1  6  0
4:  2    1  1  0  2  1
5:  2    2  2  1  0  0
```

and I perform an lapply group by id calculation:

```
my_data[,lapply(.SD,mean)*.SD,by=id,.SDcols=3:5]
```

The result is the following:

```
    id    V1    V2      V3
1:  1 1.666667 1.0  3.333333
2:  1 6.666667 1.0 10.000000
3:  1 0.000000 1.0 20.000000
4:  2 1.500000 0.0  2.000000
5:  2 3.000000 0.5  0.000000
```

**Is there an easy data table way to include the column user from the original data table?** 
I have managed to do it with

```
cbind(my_data[,.(user)], my_data[,lapply(.SD,mean)*.SD,by=id,.SDcols=3:5])
```

but i really hope there is a nicer way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do the assignment

```
my_data[,(3:5) := lapply(.SD,mean)*.SD,by=id,.SDcols=3:5]
```

Or instead of multiplying by `.SD`, we do it within the loop itself.

```
my_data[, (3:5) := lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x)*x), .SDcols = 3:5, by = id]
```

Comment: That does work thank you! But I would like to have the option 1 Not to change the original data set and 2 to add only some columns and not all of them

Comment: @George91 As you are looking for an efficient method, may be you can make a copy of the data i.e. `my_data1 <- my_data` and then do the changes in the `my_data`.  The assignment (`:=`) would be fast compared to `cbind` etc.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you go through the [vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started). The *Introduction to data.table* vignette explains an important point, which I'll repeat here..

> As long as `j` returns a *list*, each element of the list will become a column in the resulting *data.table*.

In base R, `c(list, list)` returns a new list with all the elements. We can simply use that existing functionality to do:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7 devel
dt[, c(list(user=user), lapply(.SD, function(x) x*mean(x))), by=id, .SDcols=V1:V4]
```

I'm on the [current development version of data.table, v1.9.7](http://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) which has certain new features, e.g., usage of `V1:V4` in `.SDcols`:

Comment: So from what I understand this will work from v1.9.7? Because I tried my_data[, c(list(user=user), lapply(.SD, function(x) x*mean(x))), by=id, .SDcols=3:6] and I get an error "object user not found" . Apologies if I have missunderstood

Comment: Yes, you're right. When `.SDcols` is provided, it was not possible previously to provide other variables.. This was recently fixed in v1.9.7. It'll hit CRAN as v1.9.8 (odd=devel, even=stable) soon.. But it should be fine to work with devel. See homepage for install instructions.